# How to get last item field from aggregate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I build query to get stock of each item from transaction data like this:

```
id  id_item  item_name  qty  multipler no_seal  no_pallet  Activity
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   23       Apple      20   1         SE002    PL123      IN
2   23       Apple      5    1         SE002    PL123      IN
3   23       Apple      10   -1        SE002    PL123      OUT
4   23       Apple      15   0         SE001    PL123      CHANGE_SEAL
5   23       Apple      15   0         SE001    PL055      CHANGE_PALLET
```

I try to get current stock of the item by query like this

```
SELECT id_item, item_name, SUM(qty * multipler) AS stock_qty, MAX(no_seal), MAX(no_pallet)
FROM item_transaction
GROUP BY id_item, item_name

id_item  item_name  qty     no_seal  no_pallet
-----------------------------------------------
23       Apple      15      SE002    PL123
```

but I have problem get last state of no_seal and no_pallet, aggregate function MAX() it give maximum value rather than last records,
I could use sub query to fetch max id of each item, but is it overkill to sum millions of data?

I want result stock of item id 23 (Apple) like this for no_seal and no_pallet

```
id_item  item_name  qty     no_seal  no_pallet
-----------------------------------------------
23       Apple      15      SE001    PL055
```

I'm sorry if my question is unclear, qty 15 come from
**20 (in) + 5 (in) - 10 (out) + 0 (15 item change seal) + 0 (15 item change pallet) = 15**

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you want last state for all groups or just for one

Comment: `GROUP BY id_item, item_name` should be the reason why you got one but not the last one.

Comment: What is your definition of `last`?  The row with the highest value in the `id` column, or something else?

Comment: all transactions in program insert new record with current state of item except value of quantity, it mean I must calculate qty from all transaction record, but for no_seal and no_pallet I want take it from last record of that item transaction.

Comment: You just defined last using the word last.  Please define last...  Do you mean the row with the highest id? Or do you find the "last" entry some other way?  Perhaps there is a timestamp column?

Comment: I updated my question..

Comment: That's the definition of `stock_qty`.  How Are You Determining Which Row Is The "Last" Row?  The row with the highest id? Perhaps there is a timestamp field which would be more reliable?

Comment: Yes, last record of the item in that table, of course you can choose by max of id or timestamp (I have created_at field actually)

Comment: There are numerous reasons that an id column can become unordered, which is why I say that a time stamp is more reliable. Update your question with all the relevant columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last state for one stock item, then you can use

```
select id_item,
       item_name,
       no_seal,
       no_pallet,
       (select sum(qty * multipler) from item_transaction t2 where t2.id_item = t1.id_item) qty 
from item_transaction t1
where id = (
  select max(id) 
  from item_transaction t3
  where id_item = 23
)
```

This solution assumes that `id` is unique and you want `item_transaction` with highest `id`.

Comment: I can't get stock qty with this query, qty 15 came from 20 + 5 - 10 + 0 + 0

Comment: @AnggaAriWijaya added

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inner join of max id related to the item

```
  SELECT 
      , a.item_name
      , t.stock_qty
      , a.no_seal
      , a.no_pallet
  from item_transaction a 
  inner join (
  select max(id) max_id, SUM(a.qty * a.multipler)  stock_qty,  item_name
  from item_transaction
  group by item_name ) t on t.max_id = a.item_id and t.item_name = a.item_name
  group by a.item_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT id_item, item_name, SUM(qty * multipler) AS stock_qty, MAX(id) AS last_id
    FROM item_transaction
    GROUP BY id_item, item_name
)
    summary
INNER JOIN
    item_transaction
        ON  item_transaction.id = summary.last_id
```